# How to avoid using using BuildServiceProvider method at multiple places?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a legacy `Asp.net Core 3.1` application which uses `Kestrel` server and all our `GET` and `POST` calls works fine. We have bunch of middlewares already on my legacy application and we use each of those middlewares for different purpose depending on what is the endpoint.

This is how our legacy application is setup as shown below. I have tried to keep things simple by keeping only important things.

Below is our `BaseMiddleware` class which is extended by bunch of other middlewares we have. Approx we have 10+ middlewares extending `BaseMiddleware` class -

**BaseMiddleware.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseMiddleware {
  protected static ICatalogService catalogService;
  protected static ICustomerService customerService;
  private static IDictionary <string, Object> requiredServices;

  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

  public abstract bool IsCorrectEndpoint(HttpContext context);
  public abstract string GetEndpoint(HttpContext context);
  public abstract Task HandleRequest(HttpContext context);

  public BaseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
    var builder = new StringBuilder("");
    var isMissingService = false;
    foreach(var service in requiredServices) {
      if (service.Value == null) {
        isMissingService = true;
        builder.Append(service.Key).Append(", ");
      }
    }

    if (isMissingService) {
      var errorMessage = builder.Append("cannot start server.").ToString();
      throw new Exception(errorMessage);
    }

    _next = next;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    if (IsCorrectEndpoint(context)) {
      try {
        await HandleRequest(context);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
        return;
      }
      return;
    }

    await _next.Invoke(context);
  }

  public static void InitializeDependencies(IServiceProvider provider) {
    requiredServices = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

    var catalogServiceTask = Task.Run(() => provider.GetService<ICatalogService>());
    var customerServiceTask = Task.Run(() => provider.GetService<ICustomerService>());
    // .... few other services like above approx 10+ again

    Task.WhenAll(catalogServiceTask, landingServiceTask, customerServiceTask).Wait();

    requiredServices[nameof(catalogService)] = catalogService = catalogServiceTask.Result;
    requiredServices[nameof(customerService)] = customerService = customerServiceTask.Result;
    // ....
  }
}
```

`ICatalogService` and `ICustomerService` are normal interfaces with some methods in them that their implementation class implements.

Below is one of our middlewares example that extend `BaseMiddleware`. All other middlewares follow same logic as below one -

**FirstServiceMiddleware.cs**

```
public class FirstServiceMiddleware : BaseMiddleware
{
    public FirstServiceMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) : base(next) { }

    public override bool IsCorrectEndpoint(HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/first");
    }

    public override string GetEndpoint(HttpContext context) => "/first";

    public override async Task HandleRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    }
}

public static class FirstServiceMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseFirstService(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<FirstServiceMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Below is how my `Startup` class is configured -

**Startup.cs**

```
 private static ILoggingService _loggingService;

 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
     .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
     .AddEnvironmentVariables();
   Configuration = builder.Build();
 }

 public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    });

    services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest;
    });

    DependencyBootstrap.WireUpDependencies(services);
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    if (_loggingService == null) _loggingService = provider.GetService<ILoggingService>();
    //.. some other code here

    BaseMiddleware.InitializeDependencies(provider);
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime) {
   // old legacy middlewares
   app.UseFirstService();
   // .. few other middlewares here

 }
```

And below is my `DependencyBootstrap` class -

**DependencyBootstrap.cs**

```
public static class DependencyBootstrap
{
    //.. some constants here

    public static void WireUpDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var loggingService = provider.GetService<ILoggingService>();
        // ... some other code here
        
        try
        {
            WireUp(services, loggingService);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void WireUp(IServiceCollection services, ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        // adding services here
        services.AddSingleton<....>();
        services.AddSingleton<....>();
        //....

        var localProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        if (IS_DEVELOPMENT)
        {
            processClient = null;
        }
        else
        {
            processClient = localProvider.GetService<IProcessClient>();
        }

        services.AddSingleton<IData, DataImpl>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICatalogService, CatalogServiceImpl>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICustomerService, CustomerServiceImpl>();
        //.. some other services and singleton here

    }
}
```

**Problem Statement**

I have recently started working with C# and asp.net core framework. I have done my reading and it looks like -

- Our legacy application doesn't use `Dependency Injection` properly as we have lot of places using `BuildServiceProvider` method which causes that warning. I am not sure why we have to do it.
- Also do we really need `InitializeDependencies` method in `BaseMiddleware` class? If not then how we can initialize dependencies properly? It looks like we are trying to initialize all the dependencies during server startup so that they all are ready when the call comes for any middleware. I'd like to keep this logic as it is if possible.

Currently I am confuse what is the best way to use `DI` in asp.net core and if my application is doing it wrong then how can I do it the right way? Above code works fine in our application from a very long time but looks like we might be using it totally wrong way of `DI`.

Comment: See [Access services inside ConfigureServices using IConfigureOptions in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions).

Comment: In addition to Steven's excellent answer, you should probably also look into the built-in [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/#branch-the-middleware-pipeline) extension for building your pipeline. It looks like it could replace your custom `IsCorrectEndpoint` architecture.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling `BuildServiceProvider` multiple times can cause serious trouble, because each call to `BuildServiceProvider` results in a new container instance with its own cache. This means that registrations that are expected to have the Singleton lifestyle, suddenly are created more than once. This is a problem called [Ambiguous Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl).

Some Singletons are stateless and for them there is no difference in creating one or a thousand. But other components that are registered as Singleton might have state, and the working of the application might (indirectly) depend on that state not being duplicated.

To make matters worse, while your application might work correctly today, this might change any time in the future when one of the third-party or framework components you depend on makes a change to one of their components in such way that it becomes a problem when that component is created multiple times.

In your example, you are resolving both `ILoggingService` and `IProcessClient` from a service provider. If the resolved components are stateless objects without stateful dependencies, there is no real harm done. But this might change when they become stateful. Again, this can happen by a change of one of its indirect dependencies, so this is something you might not be aware of. This can cause you or your team to waste many hours; such problem will likely not be easily found.

This means that the answer "simply" is to prevent calling `BuildServiceProvider()` to create intermediate container instances. But this might be easier said than done. In your case, specifically, you seem to require a dependency on `ILoggerService` *before* all dependencies are wired. A typical way to achieve this is to split the registration phase into two separate steps:

- One step where you manually create those few singletons that you need before hand
- Add them to your container builder (`IServiceCollection`)
- Add all other registrations

For instance:

```cs
private ILoggingService _loggingService;

public Startup(Confiration config)
{
    _loggingService = new MySpecialLoggingService(config.LogPath);
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(_loggingService);

    // More stuf here.
    ...
}
```

Advantage of this structure is that when a dependency is added to the constructor of this manually built `MySpecialLoggingService`, your code stops compiling and you're forced to look at this code. When that constructor depends on some other framework abstraction or application abstraction that isn't yet available, you know you're in trouble and need to rethink your design.

Final note, calling `BuildServiceProvider` multiple times isn't a bad thing per se. It is okay when you explicitly want to have multiple isolated modules in your application that each have their own state and run independently of one another. For instance when running multiple end points for multiple bounded contexts within the same process.

**UPDATE**

---

I think I am starting to understand what it is you are trying to achieve in your `BaseMiddleware`. It is a 'convenient' helper class that holds all the dependencies that its derivatives might need. This is probably an old design and you might be aware of this, but this base class is quite problematic. Base classes with dependencies are hardly ever a good idea, because they tend to become big, ever changing, and obfuscate the fact that their derivatives become too complex. In your case, even, you are using the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/) which is never a good idea.

Besides this, there is a lot going on in that `BaseMiddleware` class that—to me—makes little sense, such as:

- It contains complex logic to verify whether all dependencies exist, while there are more effective ways to do so. The most effective way is to apply [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/) because it will guarantee that its necessary dependencies are always available. On top of that, you can [validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149065/how-do-i-validate-the-di-container-in-asp-net-core) the `IServiceCollection` on build. This gives you even greater guarantees over the correctness of your DI configuration than your BaseMiddleware currently provides.
- It resolves all its services in background threads, which implies that construction of those components is either heavy on CPU or I/O, which is a problem. Instead composition should be fast, because [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), which allows you to [compose object graph with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).
- You do exception handling in the base class, while it is better suited to be applied at a higher level; for instance, using an outer-most piece of middleware. For the sake of simplicity, though, my next example keeps exception handling inside the base class. That's because I have no idea what kind of things you are doing in there, that could influence my answer.
- As the base class is resolving from the root container, middleware classes are only able to make use of Singleton dependencies. Connecting to the database through Entity Framework, for instance, will be a problem, because `DbContext` classes should not be captured in Singleton consumers.

So, with the observations and advice above, I would suggest reducing the `BaseMiddleware` class to the following:

```cs
// Your middleware classes should implement IMiddleware; this allows middleware
// classes to be transient and have scoped dependencies.
public abstract class ImprovedBaseMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public abstract bool IsCorrectEndpoint(HttpContext context);
    public abstract string GetEndpoint(HttpContext context);
    public abstract Task HandleRequest(HttpContext context);

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (IsCorrectEndpoint(context)) {
            try {
                await HandleRequest(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle exception here
                return;
            }
            return;
        }

        await next(context);      
    }
}
```

Now based on this new base class, create your middleware implementations similar to this next example:

```cs
public class ImprovedFirstServiceMiddleware : ImprovedBaseMiddleware
{
    private readonly ICatalogService _catalogService;
    
    // Add all dependencies required by this middleware in the constructor.
    public FirstServiceMiddleware(ICatalogService catalogService)
    {
        _catalogService = catalogService;
    }

    public override bool IsCorrectEndpoint(HttpContext context) =>
         context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/first");

    public override string GetEndpoint(HttpContext context) => "/first";

    public override async Task HandleRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from "
            + _catalogService.SomeValue());
    }
}
```

In your application, you can register your middleware classes as follows:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // When middleware implements IMiddleware, it must be registered. But
    // that's okay, because it allows the middleware with its
    // dependencies to be 'verified on build'.
    services.AddTransient<ImprovedFirstServiceMiddleware>();
    
    // If you have many middleware classes, you can use
    // Auto-Registration instead. e.g.:
    var middlewareTypes =
        from type in typeof(HomeController).Assembly.GetTypes()
        where !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericType
        where typeof(IMiddleware).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        select type;

    foreach (var middlewareType in middlewareTypes)
        services.AddTransient(middlewareType);
    
    ...
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    // Add your middleware in the correct order as you did previously.
    builder.UseMiddleware<ImprovedFirstServiceMiddleware>();
}
```

TIP: If you start to notice that a middleware classes get big constructors, that's likely because such class does too much and gets too complex. This means it should be refactored into multiple smaller classes. In that case, your class is exhibiting the [Constructor Over-Injection code smell](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/). There are many possible refactoring patterns and design patterns available that can get you out of this situation.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks for detailed explanation. I will explore that option of `ILoggingService` example you suggested. But how can I fix things I have in my  ` BaseMiddleware.InitializeDependencies` method? I am not sure why we have like that but any idea what I can do there in that whole class? Specifically `BaseMiddleware` constructor and `InitializeDependencies` method?

Comment: It's really great. Thanks for detailed explanation. Let me go through all those point and read in detail. It is clearing all my doubts basically. Appreciate your help really!

Comment: Sorry I was away for a while so couldn't respond. I tried this approach and it works for me but what I am noticing is dependencies gets initialized during the first call to any middleware. Meaning only those dependencies gets initialized which are dependent on the middleware we are calling for the first time. And other dependencies will be initialized if their corresponding middleware will be called for the first time. Is there any way we can initialize **all** the dependencies during **server startup** just like I was doing in my previous approach? @Steven

Comment: If my understanding is clear `BaseMiddleware.InitializeDependencies` in old code was initializing all dependencies during server startup so that whenever the call comes to any middleware all dependencies are already ready. In some of my dependencies, we have some work being done in constructor to load some objects in memory.

Comment: Read my bullet points of my update again closely. These should answer your questions.

Comment: yup I read that again in your point 2 bullet and you are right that some of those dependencies do some heavy lifting but since this is a legacy application so changing all those around will be very tough here. Is there any way you can think of by which we can initialize all the dependencies during server startup in a safe way with your new implementation? Just trying to see if there is any possibility here. @Steven

Comment: You mean doing like the way you showed for `ILoggingService _loggingService;` line in `Startup` class? or there is any better way?

Comment: I think having this loading logic inside the startup is the most obvious, most discoverable place.

Comment: Quick question - what is `HomeController` in your auto registration of middleware? Do I need to bring that in from some namespace or it is something else there? @Steven

Comment: To get an assembly to scan, it is often useful to take a type that you know is in that assembly. Than you take the Type.Assembly. HomeController itself is irrelevant, but I took it, because HomeController will usually be part of the MVC/startup assembly, which will (likely) also contain your middleware.