# dependency injection and multiple filesystemwatcher's

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

This is mostly a design question.

I use the System.IO.Abstraction library. It has a `IFileSystemWatcher` that I can inject into my service.

The issue is that I have multiple paths I wish to watch. And the watcher cannot do that.

So I need to somehow find a good solution for doing this.

I have thought about doing it in the startup of the application.

E.g

```
services.AddTransient<IFileSystemWatcher,FileSystemWatcher>();

foreach(var fileToWatch in files)
{
    var fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(fileToWatch);
    services.AddSingleton<IFileWatcher>(fileWatcher);
}
```

The `FileWatcher` has a dependency on the `IFileSystemWatcher`.

The only other option I can think of without newing up a `FileSystemWatcher` inside the `FileWatcher`, which i don't want to due to testability, is to add the give the `FileWatcher` the `ServiceProvider` and from there do a `ServiceProvider.GetService<IFileSystemWatcher>` inside of that, and from there somehow make my way around it like that. I don't find that solution really nice.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered injecting a factory?

Comment: What about calling `services.AddSingleton<IFileWatcher>(c => new FileWatcher(fileToWatch, c.GetRequiredService<IFileSystemWatcher>())`?

Comment: @Steven yes, that could work

Answer (score 1):

i ended up with a solution that i have a hard time accepting. I never like to have a BuildServiceProvider anywhere. But at least i get to use a factory which makes sense, and the service at hand is testable.

program.cs

```
... ...
services.AddSingleton<IFileSystemWatcherFactory, FileSystemWatcherFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<IFileWatcher, FileWatcher>();

//bootstrap filewatcher
//must be after ifilewatcher registry in DI
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var fileWatcher = serviceProvider.GetService<IFileWatcher>();
fileWatcher.FileWatch().Wait();
```

FileWatcher.cs

```cs
public class FileWatcher : IFileWatcher
{
    private readonly IEventChannel _eventProducer;
    private readonly IFileSystemWatcherFactory _watcher;
    private readonly BookSmartsOptions _bookSmartsOptions;

    public FileWatcher(IEventChannel eventProducer,
        IFileSystemWatcherFactory watcher, IOptions<BookSmartsOptions> options)
    {
        _eventProducer = eventProducer;
        _watcher = watcher;
        _bookSmartsOptions = options.Value;
    }

    public async Task FileWatch()
    {
        foreach (var folderToWatch in _bookSmartsOptions.FilesToWatch.Split(';'))
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                var watch = _watcher.CreateNew(folderToWatch, "*.txt");
                watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                watch.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
            }).ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted) throw t.Exception;
            });
        }
    }

    private async void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object s, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        => await _eventProducer.Write(e.FullPath);
}
```

Any other comments?

Comment: Please note that call `BuildServiceProvider` fro your code can have serious negative consequences, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264937/264697). Whether there is a risk for you, however, is hard for me to say. Instead, in case the created objects are simple in structure, you could also opt for creating this part of the graph by hand, instead of moving the responsibility to the DI Container. In other words, just call `new FileSystemWatcher()`.

Comment: @Steven yes, i know and that's why i really don't like it. I started the implementation by creating the FileSystemWatcher but then I thought about the testability.

I could also move the fileWatcher.FileWatch().Wait(); to the constructor of the FileWatcher and then i wouldn't have to joggle with the DI provider in the bootstrapping of the app.