# Can I make an instance of a service in configureservices method in startup (.NET Core) and add a list to a property?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, startup

I need to convert old VB.NET code to c# in a new .NET core solution. In the old code they use [Ninject modules](http://www.ninject.org/). In one of these modules they make an instance of a service and add a list of handlers to it.

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports AnC.Services.EventService.Shared.Interfaces ' for IEventHandler 

Class MyModule
    Inherits NinjectModule ' See https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel 

    Public Overrides Sub Load()

        Dim es As New EventService(Me.Kernel.Get(Of IEventLogRepository), Me.Kernel.Get(Of IEventRepository), Me.Kernel.Get(Of ISelfInstallImportEdiOrder))

        Dim handlers As New List(Of IEventHandler)
                
        ' (Add IEventHandler instances to `handlers` list here)

        es.EventHandlers = handlers

        Bind(Of EventService).ToConstant(es)

    End Sub

End Class
```

In the new code I want to do something similar in the `StartUp` class' `ConfigureServices` method, something like:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider; // for `ServiceProvider`
using AnC.Services.EventService.Shared.Interfaces; // for `IEventHandler`

void ConfigureServices( ServiceCollection services )
{
    services.AddScoped<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IEventLogRepository, EventLogRepository>();

    List<IEventHandler> handlers = new List<IEventHandler>();

    // (Add IEventHandler instances to `handlers` list here)

    ServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    EventService    es = new EventService( sp.GetRequiredService<IEventLogRepository>(), sp.GetRequiredService<IEventRepository>() );
    es.EventHandlers = handlers;

    services.AddSingleton<IEventService,EventService>( sp => es );
}
```

I read that calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` is something you better avoid because of possible duplicates of singletons. There are no singleton's registered before this call in my code.

Is this a correct approach I'm using? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: _"Is this a correct approach I'm using?"_ - in a word, **_no_**, sorry.

Comment: _"Is there a better way to do this?"_ - yes, but first, please tell us _what is the purpose_ of `EventService`? ...and why does it needs to exist inside `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: _"I read that calling '`services.BuildServiceProvider()`' is something you better avoid because of possible duplicates of singletons."_ - well, that's _one_ reason, but (I personally) feel the main reason is because it's simply not using .NET Core's DI system the way it's intended to be used, which will inevitably cause unrelated or unexpected problems that will take forever to solve because it won't be a documented or supported use-case.

Comment: @Dai Could these list be added to DI as singleton, and than be gotten from EventService class constructor?

Comment: Also, we **really** need to know what exactly happens inside `// add to handlers list` because passing delegates around (or even worse: Java-style single-method interfaces) for subscribing to events in a DI system is _dangerous_ because it means you'll leak strong references that will exceed object lifetime (e.g. a singleton service subscribing to a transient's events). There are better alternatives for runtime-subscribable events than this... but I can't recommend an alternative without more information about your project.

Comment: @kanils_ Yes, but it's too soon to suggest that as a solution as there's still far too many details about the OP's situation we don't know about... details which would radically change whatever the actual solution for them will be.

Comment: @Dai thnx for your comments. The purpose of the EventService is to handle serveral events, these are the events in the handlers list (added like: "handlers.Add(New SomeEventHandler(Me.Kernel.Get(Of ISomeRegisteredRepository)()))"), to see if they need to be executed. The EventService itself is triggered elsewhere every x minutes. Every event is different and needs to execute different actions. What I actually need is a proper/best way to access this list of eventhandlers that need to be checked if execution is needed whithout causing (DI) problems.

Comment: @D.Brugmans `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` already supports dependency-validation, so you shouldn't need to "check" anything yourself. So anyway, what you're saying is that you're only instantiating `EventService` so early because you want your program to fail-fast if _any_ hardcoded event-handler (not event-listeners?) cannot be resolved? Well, if the list is hardcoded then this whole exercise is moot and you can use "traditional" DI for that - but that's still a bad design overall, imo. Point is: let the DI system handle dependency-validation for you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264937/264697

Answer (score 1):

This would be the equivalent in MS.DI:

```
// NOTE: These are now singletons, because is EventService is singleton
// Please make sure you understand the concept of Captive Dependencies.
services.AddSingleton<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<IEventLogRepository, EventLogRepository>();

List<IEventHandler> handlers = new List<IEventHandler>();

// (Add IEventHandler instances to `handlers` list here)

services.AddSingleton<IEventService>(c =>
{
    // Create EventService using Constructor Injection:
    var es = new EventService(
        c.GetRequiredService<IEventLogRepository>(),
        c.GetRequiredService<IEventRepository>());

    // Apply Property injection:
    es.EventHandlers = handlers;

    return es;
});
```

A better approach, however, might be to move away from [Property Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-property-injection/) and inject the `IEventHandler` implementations using Constructor Injection instead:

```cs
// EventService ctor:
public EventService(
    IEventLogRepository eventLogRepo,
    IEventRepository eventRepo,
    IEnumerable<IEventHandler> handlers)
```

This leads to the following registrations:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<IEventLogRepository, EventLogRepository>();

// Add IEventHandler instances, e.g.:
services.AddSingleton<IEventHandler>(new EventHandler1());
services.AddSingleton<IEventHandler>(new EventHandler2());
services.AddSingleton<IEventHandler>(new EventHandler3());
services.AddSingleton<IEventHandler, EventHandler4>();

services.AddSingleton<IEventService, EventService>();
```

The advantage of this approach is that it allows `IEventHandler` implementations to be registered in the container. This allows handlers to get dependencies of their own, injected into their constructors, which is something that you can see in the registration for `EventHandler4` in the previous example.

Please prevent calling `BuildServiceProvider` anywhere in your code, because that can lead to a myriad of problems, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264937/264697).