# DI/HttpContext in custom ConsoleFormatter

Tags: c#, .net, logging, console, dependency-inversion

In my custom `ConsoleFormatter` I need to get a value from a service added to the DI. This value is saved in a SCOPED service because it generates a new value for every new request but should keep the value through the request.

The problem is that I don't know how to access a DI service in the `ConsoleFormatter`, what I've tried below is to put the services container into the options parameter. My thoughts here is that .NET Services is a singleton, and by this I can request my service at the logging time and get my scoped service.

```
public static class ConsoleLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomConsoleFormatter(
    this ILoggingBuilder builder, Action<CustomConsoleFormatterOptions> options)
    {
        return builder.AddConsole(
            options => options.FormatterName = nameof(CustomLoggingFormatter))
            .AddConsoleFormatter<
                CustomLoggingFormatter, CustomConsoleFormatterOptions>(
                options);
    }
}

public sealed class CustomConsoleFormatterOptions : ConsoleFormatterOptions
{
    public IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CustomLoggingFormatter : ConsoleFormatter, IDisposable
{
    static long RowIndex = 1;
    readonly IDisposable _optionsReloadToken;
    CustomConsoleFormatterOptions _formatterOptions;

    public CustomLoggingFormatter(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomConsoleFormatterOptions> options)
        : base(nameof(SebLoggingFormatter))
    {
        (_optionsReloadToken, _formatterOptions) =
            (options.OnChange(ReloadLoggerOptions), options.CurrentValue);
    }

    public override void Write<TState>(in LogEntry<TState> logEntry,
        IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        string message =
            logEntry.Formatter?.Invoke(logEntry.State, logEntry.Exception);
        if (message is null)
            return;

        var idService =
            _formatterOptions.serviceProvider.GetService<IIdService>();
        var requestId = idService.RequestId;
    }

    void ReloadLoggerOptions(CustomConsoleFormatterOptions options) =>
        _formatterOptions = options;

    public void Dispose() =>
        _optionsReloadToken?.Dispose();
}
```

And in my startup I add a Task to get the CustomFormnaytterOptions

```
services.AddLogging(opt => opt.AddCustomConsoleFormatter(options =>
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    options.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}));
```

But when I request the IdService from the services I get back a service with an empty  Value, and for me that might be coz:

- No http-context (IdService is picking or creating the Id by the headers in the current request)
- The .net Services I use here is something old from the time at startup (=not a singleton) and therefor not related to the current request

One thing I don't understand is this Option-coding-pattern that (ConsoleFormatterOptions uses) in .net, seems to be a built in feature. Should I in some way try to invalidate the options so it re-runs the task from startup?

Comment: So I've done some debugging here (added a created-time to the constructor in the IdService) and the IdService I get back from .net Services is indeed an old one from the time of startup - and I want the current one from the request. I guess the CustomConsole does not have a HttpContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your solution that prevent it from working:

- Setting the `CustomConsoleFormatterOptions.serviceProvider` field to `services.BuildServiceProvider()` will cause your formatter it to get a copy of all DI registrations. This won't give you access to the requests `IIdService`, and won't get you access to the active scope or HTTP request.
- Calling `BuildServiceProvider` multiple times is a [problematic practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264937/264697), which is why there is a code analyzer in .NET Core that will warn you about this.
- Loggers and their formatters are always assumed singletons by the framework. Although formatters can have dependencies injected into them, those dependencies are, should be, or will become singletons by themselves. If you inject the `IServiceProvider`, it will be the 'root' service provider, and won't give you access to scoped services.

The solution is to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` class, as it allows accessing the current `HttpContext`:

```
public sealed class CustomLoggingFormatter : ConsoleFormatter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public CustomLoggingFormatter(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        : base(nameof(SebLoggingFormatter))
    {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public override void Write<TState>(in LogEntry<TState> logEntry,
        IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        string message =
            logEntry.Formatter?.Invoke(logEntry.State, logEntry.Exception);
        if (message is null)
            return;

        // Pull scoped service from request
        var idService =
            this.accessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IIdService>();

        var requestId = idService.RequestId;
    }
}
```

This can be wired up as follows:

```cs
builder.AddHttpAccessor();

builder.AddConsole(
    options => options.FormatterName = nameof(CustomLoggingFormatter))
    .AddConsoleFormatter<
        CustomLoggingFormatter, CustomConsoleFormatterOptions>();
```

Comment: That's awesome, haha, so easy, just to inject the IHttpContextAccessor :-) I did actually manage to get it to work by doing the same thing, first use my services and request thge HttpContextAccessor and then request the IdService from that DiContainer. But of course your way is the only correct way. A big thank you for the help!