# InvalidOperationException: Service Not Registered in ASP.NET Core Worker Service

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application with a `BackgroundService` where I'm facing an issue with dependency injection. I've set up a generic repository pattern and have registered my services in Program.cs. However, when the application runs, it throws an `InvalidOperationException`, indicating that the service for `IGenericRepository<Configuration>` hasn't been registered.

Despite following the standard procedure for registering services and ensuring that the namespaces and configurations are correct, the application fails to resolve this specific service. I'm looking for insights or suggestions to identify and fix the root cause of this issue.

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Cavipetrol.Domain.Interface.Repositories.IGenericRepository`1[Cavipetrol.Domain.Entities.Configuration]' has been registered.

The error occurs in my Worker class:

```cs
var configurationRepository =
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGenericRepository<Configuration>>();
```

I have registered the service in Program.cs like this:

```
services.AddScoped<
    IGenericRepository<Configuration>,
    GenericRepository<Configuration>>();
```

And my implementation of IGenericRepository is as follows:

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<bool> Add(T entity);
    Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    public bool Update(T entity);
    Task<T> FindOneByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    Task<T> GetMostRecentRecord(
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> dateSelector,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

The Configuration class is defined as:

```cs
[Table("Configuration")]
public class Configuration : ClassBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the StackTrace of the error:

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Cavipetrol.Transactional.MemosViajeros.Worker.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in P:\Proyectos\Cavipetrol\Code\NuevoPortal-Backend\Cavipetrol.Transactional\Cavipetrol.Transactional\Cavipetrol.Transactional.MemosViajeros\Worker.cs: line 43
```

In my attempts to resolve this issue, I double-checked the registration of my services in Program.cs and confirmed the correct implementation of `IGenericRepository<T>` and its concrete class `GenericRepository<T>`. I expected that the service would be resolved successfully during runtime, allowing the `BackgroundService` to utilize the `IGenericRepository<Configuration>` for database operations. However, contrary to my expectations, the application throws an `InvalidOperationException` when trying to resolve this service, indicating it's not registered, despite the clear registration in the service configuration. This unexpected behavior is puzzling and I'm seeking advice on potential causes and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When MS.DI states that "No service for type 'X' has been registered", it really means that there is no registration X. You provide to little information to point the exact reason, but here are the reasons I can think of why this could happen in your case:

1. The registered `IGenericRepository<T>` is a different type to the resolved `Cavipetrol.Domain.Interface.Repositories.IGenericRepository<T>`. This can easily happen because VS (and other IDEs) make it very easy to accidentally generate a new type with that name with a simple key press. Double check whether both the registered interface and the resolved interface point at the same type.
2. Similarly, the `Cavipetrol.Domain.Entities.Configuration` of the resolved interface could point to a different type than the `Configuration` in the registered interface.
3. Although you show that the registration is made in the `IServiceCollection` interface, it is possible to (accidentally) build an `IServiceProvider` before that happened. Such service provider will not contain any registrations that haven't been made before that point in time. It is possible that the background worker is supplied with such an 'extra' service provider. Best practice is to only have one service provider instance for the entire application and to let the framework create it. In other words, prevent calling `BuildServiceProvider` manually yourself as that could lead to [all sorts of issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264937/264697)